# Prestashop 1.7.5.1 - language switcher not visible on mobile view

Tags: mobile, prestashop-1.7

I am using Prestshop 1.7.5.1 version. On desktop view language switcher is visible but on mobile view it is not loading. I'm using `ps_languageselector` module. My .tpl code is here

```
<div id="_desktop_language_selector">
  <div class="lang_change_block col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-1 clearfix">
    <div class="language-selector-wrapper">
      <span class="hidden-md-up">{l s='Language:' d='Shop.Theme'}</span>
      <div class="language-selector dropdown js-dropdown">
        <span class="expand-more hidden-sm-down" data-toggle="dropdown">{$current_language.name_simple}</span>
        <a data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="hidden-sm-down">
          <i class="material-icons expand-more">&#xE5C5;</i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu hidden-sm-down">
          {foreach from=$languages item=language}
            <li {if $language.id_lang == $current_language.id_lang} class="current" {/if}>
              <a href="{url entity='language' id=$language.id_lang}" class="dropdown-item">{$language.name_simple}</a>
            </li>
          {/foreach}
        </ul>
        <select class="link hidden-md-up">
          {foreach from=$languages item=language}
            <option value="{url entity='language' id=$language.id_lang}"{if $language.id_lang == $current_language.id_lang} selected="selected"{/if}>{$language.name_simple}</option>
          {/foreach}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

to my mind, you should see the class on your select 'hidden-md-up' and 'hidden-sm-down'

> ```
> <ul class="dropdown-menu **hidden-sm-down**">
>     {foreach from=$languages item=language}
>         <li {if $language.id_lang == $current_language.id_lang} class="current" {/if}>
>             <a href="{url entity='language' id=$language.id_lang}" class="dropdown-item">{$language.name_simple}</a>
>         </li>
>     {/foreach}
> </ul>
> <select class="link **hidden-md-up**">
>       {foreach from=$languages item=language}
>         <option value="{url entity='language' id=$language.id_lang}"{if $language.id_lang == $current_language.id_lang} selected="selected"{/if}>{$language.name_simple}</option>
>       {/foreach}
>  </select>
> ```

For more information with this class : https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was another add-on which was causing the issue. As soon as I set the add-on to 'desable mobile' I could see the lang and currency selector. Also the logo was suddenly in the right place on top of the page. Before it was a bit below.

So, it's maybe no programming issue as such with the lang add-on but with another add-on.

Kindly,